# Caching in PlayOrm

Tags: playorm

I want to know more about how caching works in playorm. Any pointers would be great.
Also:
1. If there are any performance numbers available which validate caching in Playorm. 
2. Is there any configuration/setting required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caching in playorm is ALOT like caching in hibernate.  There are really two caches going on which may be called the write cache and the read cache.

The write cache is that as you do a put(Object entity), put(Object entity), etc. etc. it is caching those puts in a class called NoSqlWriteCacheImpl.  When you call flush, this cache is emptied out and cleared.  There is no way to clear this cache without flushing it.  Calling clear does NOT clear this cache, only calling flush does so don't do a put if you don't want to write something.  This cache is PER NoSqlEntityManager.

Then the read cache is in a class called NoSqlReadCacheImpl.  This cache is just like hibernate's 1st level cache and is PER NoSqlEntityManager just like hibernate.  As you read stuff in, it goes through this layer and is cached and as you read that stuff in again, it is read form the cache instead of going to the nosql database.  A great example is you get a tshirt and then get it's User(say bob) and then you get some other object and get it's User which happens to be Bob....this results in a cache hit and happens more frequently than one would expect as they query stuff.  NOTE: The NoSqlReadCache is completely avoided when running any NoSqlQuery!!!!  It is only used on the find(Class c, List keys) and find(Class c, Object key) methods.